# iOS ignores input report of Consumer Page of HID over Gatt

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid

I use CSR1010 and wrote a BLE HID over Gatt application which sends only Play/Pause, Volume Increment/Decrement to iOS.

The report descriptor of the consumer report was configured as:

```
05 0C        (GLOBAL) USAGE_PAGE         0x000C Consumer Device Page
09 01        (LOCAL)  USAGE              0x000C0001 Consumer Control (CA=Application Collection)
A1 01        (MAIN)   COLLECTION         0x01 Application (Usage=0x000C0001: Page=Consumer Device Page, Usage=Consumer Control, Type=CA)
85 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_ID          0x01 (1)
19 00          (LOCAL)  USAGE_MINIMUM      0x000C0000 Unassigned
2A 9C02        (LOCAL)  USAGE_MAXIMUM      0x000C029C AC Distribute Vertically (Sel=Selector)
15 00          (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MINIMUM    0x00 (0) <-- Redundant: LOGICAL_MINIMUM is already 0
26 9C02        (GLOBAL) LOGICAL_MAXIMUM    0x029C (668)
95 01          (GLOBAL) REPORT_COUNT       0x01 (1) Number of fields
75 10          (GLOBAL) REPORT_SIZE        0x10 (16) Number of bits per field
81 00          (MAIN)   INPUT              0x00000000 (1 field x 16 bits) 0=Data 0=Array 0=Absolute 0=Ignored 0=Ignored 0=PrefState 0=NoNull
C0           (MAIN)   END_COLLECTION     Application
```

I validated this report descriptor using [hidrdd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hidrdd/) so I am quite confident that it will be parsed fine.

The raw data bytes sent to iOS as shown in the sniffer were `05 0c 09 01 a1 01 85 01 19 00 2a 9c 02 15 00 26 9c 02 95 01 75 10 81 00 c0` which is exactly as configured.

I also saw from the sniff result that iOS registered for notification from Client Character Configuration of the consumer report characteristic.

Everything looks good but when I send 2 bytes `0xcd 0x00` (Play/Pause) to iOS, nothing happens.

Now I just felt like I did everything I could but iOS was still unhappy. There is no way to tell what iOS is unhappy about because there is no iOS app involved. Can anybody who has experience in this give me some pointers?

[EDIT]
Added some screenshots of the sniffer below:

[image: Report Map 1st part]
[image: Report Map 2nd part]
[image: iOS writes client configuration]
[image: HID report ignored by iOS]

Comment: Doing something similar in iOS. Need to connect my iOS to an external hardware using Bluetooth Dongle (BLE HID over Gatt). And i want the Dongle to pass keyboard strokes to iPhone. Is it possible ? Can you explain  if it's possible. !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you include a report id in your report descriptor then all HID reports (on that interface) must be prefixed with a report id. In your case you would need to send a 3 byte report:

```
0x01 0xcd 0x00
```

...or remove the report id from your report descriptor.

Comment: That really worked. Thanks! What still confuses me is that in [HID over Gatt](https://www.bluetooth.org/docman/handlers/downloaddoc.ashx?doc_id=245141) specifies that **Report ID is 
prepended to data received by the Report Host** on Page 22, which makes me think that I don't have to prepend report id myself. I actually captured CSR's remote control's packets and the demo also just sends out `0xb0 0x00` and `0xb1 0x00` without specifying report ID as the first byte and it can successfully play/pause music.

Comment: Actually my code, as I later tested after posting this question, works with an Android 4.4 tablet with `0xcd 0x00` only. Anyway, I just feel rather confused...